# DI with Unity Container - Best practices resolving with additional parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

Example:

`IApple` and implementation `Apple`. Constructor of `Apple`:

`public Apple(IVitamin vitamin, int size)`

I can register all DIs and IApple:

```
container.RegisterType<IApple,Apple>();
container.RegisterInstance<IVitamin>(vitamin);
```

I can now override parameters when creating an instance of apple to insert the int size parameter:

```
var apple = container.Resolve<IApple>(new ParameterOverrides<Apple> {{"size", 9001}}
```

It seems bothersome that you have to write the string of the parameter in there ("size"). Is this the prefered way to do DI when there are other parameters involved? Or do I have to create a AppleFactory (or in general a factory) that handles that? (It seems overkill to have to write a factory for every class that has non-DI properties as well as DI ones.

Or should you not override and Set the property manually?

```
var apple = container.Resolve<IApple>();
apple.Size = 9001;
```

This way the code logic would be transferred from constructor to setter of the property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems bothersome that you have to write the string of the parameter in there ("size")

Yeah, it's ugly, but there's no way around it, at least not with Unity.

> It seems overkill to have to write a factory for every class that has non-DI properties as well as DI ones

True, but it's probably what you should do anyway. Most of your code shouldn't depend directly on the container.

If you make a factory, the parameter override isn't quite as ugly, because you can use `nameof` instead of a string:

```
class AppleFactory : IAppleFactory
{
    ...

    public IApple CreateApple(int size)
    {
        return _container.Resolve<IApple>(new ParameterOverrides<Apple> {{nameof(size), size}};
    }
}
```

An alternative is to use my [Unity.Extras.AutoFactory](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/Unity.Extras.AutoFactory) extension, but keep in mind it's in alpha state...

Comment: I always thought factories are used when you have to do a lot "special" instantiation underneath. So calling ... = new X() is critical while using the factory everything is save. 
it sounds like when using DI Containers you have to create factories for 60% of the classes....

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to think why would you inject an `integer` into the class that way. If every `Apple` instantiated using unity gets injected the same value, is the value a constant? If yes, you don't really need to inject it. It can just be part of an `Apple`. But in your example, if `Apple` represents an entity or an object with a state and can have different size, `Factory` definitely seems like a better option. `Factory` will end up setting the values of properties during initialization. If you are testing your code, you will do yourself a favour moving these sort of decisions into a `Factory` and keeping you IoC container configuration focused on building dependency tree rather than dealing with values for an initial state of objects.

Comment: You are right in this example the factory is clearly the better option. Consider an AppleWorker which needs to be resolved. It's always the same implementation of AppleWorker but you have to pass in a different Apple every time. The worker does not care what kind of apple and it always works the same. public AppleWorker(ITool tool, Apple apple). So ITool would be DI resolved and apple just passed.

Comment: Do you expect AppleWorker to only ever deal with one Apple? If not method injection sounds more appropriate. That way the decision of what apple should be passed to a worker is with the class/method asking worker to do work with Apple. AppleWorker(ITool tool) and then _appleWorker.DoWork(apple)

Comment: Looks like the solution I am looking for. But this way my DoWork(Apple apple) class will have to do all the initialization that uses the apple which was before in the constructor. e.g. AppleAnalyzer analyzer = new AppleAnalyzer(apple); Or I have to register the AppleAnalyser to unity as well and then we start with the original problem that I have to pass a property to it.

Comment: I would pass Apple to Analyzer through a method rather than constructor. So most likely use a factory to create an instance of a specific apple and then pass it to Analyzer's public method as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I think your example is too simplified. If you're going to create apples of different sizes, you probably are not going to resolve them from the container (it is a bit strange the way you are creating the apples thru the container, it really looks more appropriate for `factory` then `container`).

Don't forget that the main purpose for the container is to wire up complex object compositions / dependencies which should be able to be created from the current state of the container. When you find yourself supplying arguments for the Resolve method i thinks you should stop and try to avoid it , probably some redesign, refactoring is the right direction to go.

**Side Note**:

In most of cases when i need to inject primitive i would use struct / class something like this

```
public struct AppleSize {
     public int Value { get; }
     .....
}
```

Now i can register instance of `AppleSize` in the `container`
and the Apple constructor will use `AppleSize` instead of the `int`. Avoid registration of primitives. Better use more descriptive structs / class definitions.

If the scenario is more **complex** (the primitive to be injected could depend on too many arguments and needs to be calculated / manipulated) then i would create `factory` to **encapsulate any actions related with the creation of the object**, which is more close to your scenario i think.